# What this "get" in JavaScript object means?

Tags: javascript

Look at this script:

```
var human = 
{
   firstName: 'Saeed',
   lastName: 'Neamati',
   get fullName() {
       return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
   }
}
```

I don't know what `get` means in this context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Javascript have get/set keywords like C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409372/does-javascript-have-get-set-keywords-like-c)

Answer (score 7):

It identifies an object *property* that's returned when the property is read.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/get

Comment: This only works in ES5. It's saver to use `Object.defineProperty` with a proper shim

Comment: It seems to be reasonably well supported in non-ie browsers; http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html#regular-getters-and-setters

Comment: [It works](http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html#regular-getters-and-setters) on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera.  Not IE.  OMG, Microsoft failed to adhere to a standard, making life worse for thousands of developers and millions of users!  We better alert the media.  This is going to be huge news!  Microsoft's impeccable reputation will be in tatters!

Comment: @Malvolio It does work in all browser apart from IE<9. But the point is that this syntax can not degrade gracefully, ever. Almost all other ES5 features can degrade gracefully.

Comment: @Raynos -- which is why I encourage people to take advantage of the IE [memory-cycle bug](http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html), so that users have more obvious reasons to upgrade their IE to a real browser.  While any significant number of people still use IE, the course of human progress will be measurably slowed.

Comment: @Malvolio or the IE users just do not go back to your site ;)

Comment: @epascarello -- that's the best part!  The leakage isn't traceable back to my site.  They visit my site, and a dozen others, and then an hour or two later, their IE does what IE does and crashes.  My hands are clean! [pinkie finger to corner of mouth] Mwa-ha-ha-ha!

Answer (score 4):

It´s a property.
You can use it like this:

```
console.log(human.fullName); //Saeed Neamati
```

It´s a function that is called when accessing this property, and returns the value.

There are also setters available:

```
var human = 
{
   firstName: 'Saeed',
   lastName: 'Neamati',
   get fullName() {
       return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
   }
   set fullName(val) {
       var parts = val.split(' ');
       this.firstName = parts[0];
       this.lastName = parts[1];
   }
}

human.fullName = "Henry Miller";
```

But as cool as it might be, it´s not supported by all browsers. So it might be better avoid using it.