# Why do we use “get” keyword in Vue Project?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

In a project where I am working(Vue.JS Project) I found in so many places they have used this 'get' before the function, but I am not clear yet why do we need that. I have added one function with this get:

```
  get dataNotYetArrived(): boolean {
    return justAnExample;
  }
```

It will be helpful if someone can explain this to me. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "get" keyword before a function in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999259/what-is-the-get-keyword-before-a-function-in-a-class) and [What this “get” in JavaScript object means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401048)

Comment: Not exactly the same one but I got some valuable idea after watching that post. Thanks mate.

Comment: `get` is a javascript keyword nothing specific to Vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `getter` syntax. It's a Javascript feature that assigns a function to be executed when accessing the property -- which is useful when you want the property to return something dynamic, rather than a static value. So:

```
get someProperty() { ... }
```

executes the function `someProperty()` when you access `myInstance.someProperty`.

More here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get